kubernetes nodeport service not responding
Here is my deploy yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: some-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: some-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: some-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: some-api-local
        image: "ealen/echo-server:0.9.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: registrycred

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: some-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5001
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30002
  selector:
    app: some-api

The actual service is running on port 80 with logs spitting just below:

Just experimenting with kubernetes cluster deployments. I am trying to access a simple echo server via this service above like this:
10.109.89.108:30002
Output of: k get nodes --output wide

The ip above is my cluster IP that I got from kubectl get service. What I am doing wrong?
Tried to access as below:

192.168.49.2:30002 (using node ip)
10.109.89.108:30002 (cluster ip)



The ip above is my cluster IP that I got from kubectl get service.

Try [node IP]:30002 to access the port. You can find the node IP with kubectl get nodes --output wide.
For minikube, run minikube service some-service --url before browsing to http://localhost:30002. More details here.

this didn't worked, I already tried this!

see my edit with the output of get nodes: 192.168.49.2 :30002 should work correct

Can you edit to add the exact command you use to access 192.168.49.2:30002, the error message and clarify on which node you execute this command.

here is the command: kubectl get nodes --output wide and there is only one node listed (minikube)

No, this is the command given in the answer. Add the command that you use to access the 192.168.49.2:30002, eg. curl?

just this in the browser: 192.168.49.2:30002

yeah this works. one question though: how do you typically do local development - this minikube doesn't look very viable - I am on macOS. Any suggestions? Locally just work usually and publish images using docker. Then run these kubernetes orchestrations directly in the environments?

I am trying to run this API in a local kubernetes cluster and frontend has to access it (locally), with this dynamic tunnelling it might be a pain to connect everytime?

Typically, you only need to create the tunnel once.

thanks! that helps a lot. Last thing, is there a way to choose the port with this minikube service command?

You can't choose the port # when using minikube service command.

You have 4 different ports defined. You have a container port of 3001, a Service listening on 5001 that forwards to 80, with nodes proxying connections to port 300002 to your Service.
Whichever port your application runs on (I assume 3001), should be your targetPort, and its convenient if you're connecting through the node anyway (with some external load balancer) to have your Service port also be the same.
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: some-api-local
        image: "ealen/echo-server:0.9.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001 # is this the port that echo-server runs on?
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: registrycred

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: some-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5001 # port the service listens on
    targetPort: 80 # port the app runs on
    nodePort: 30002 # using Nodes as proxy with external LB
  selector:
    app: some-api



Hi, see my edit: container port and target port are now both 80 with the same issue!

Try this as a first step. Check if your pod even responds to the http request: kubectl run --rm curl --image=curlimages/curl -- curl http://:80

Your answer looks like a good starting point for debugging the problem. However, it does not solve the issue nor does it provide possible solutions. It migt be better to post it as a comment instead, because it requires action from the person who asked the original question.
